# Ciclo for dentro de una funcion no se ejecuta

Tags: javascript

Tengo un problema con mi codigo, necesito que el mismo dibuje en canvas tantos guiones como letras tenga un un string (que forma parte de un array, es para un juego del ahorcado). Para hacerlo quiero usar un for dentro de la funcion que dibuja los guiones, usando como condicion i < array.length, pero por algun motivo el mismo no se ejecuta, al inspeccionar tampoco aparece ningun error. Dejo mi codigo

```
let palabras = ["JAVA","CSS","HTML","VARIABLE","FUNCION","HTML"];
let palabra = "";

function dibujarLineas(){
    ctx.strokeStyle ="blue";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=2;

    let ancho = (600/palabra.length);
    for (var i=0 ; i < palabra.length ; i++){
        ctx.moveTo(50 + (ancho*i), 360);
        ctx.lineTo(100 + (ancho*i), 360);
        console.log(i);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

}
function iniciar(){
    let palabra = palabras[Math.floor(Math.random()*palabras.length)];
    console.log(palabra);
    dibujarLineas();
}
```

Alguna idea de porque no funciona? Gracias !!

Comment: Si funciona, funciona perfectamente de hecho. El problema es que usas funciones que no devuelven nada, y en `iniciar()` sobreescribes la variable `palabra` creando una nueva (`let palabra = palabras[Math.floor...`). Quita ese `let` y debería funcionarte. Cuando utilizas `let` estás creando tu palabra en el *"scope"* en que te encuentras en ese momento, en este caso, la variable `palabra` de dentro de `iniciar()` declarada con `let` **solo existe dentro de la función `iniciar`!**

Comment: Efectivamente era por eso. Gracias !!!!!!!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!